# Laravel5.3: How to implement further relationship in Pivot Table in Many Many Relationship?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, many-to-many

So I have this below simple DB structure where I am doing a Many to Many relationship between `Users` & `Roles`.

[image]

I have managed to do  the Many to Many relationships so I can get:

`$user->roles()` as well as `role->users()`, however, as you can see I have an additional column in pivot table `user_roles` i.e. `author_id` who is the person who granted this role. This is again a one to one relation to a `Users` table.

My question is how can I establish this relationship in pivot table, so I am able to do:

```
    @foreach($role->users as $user)
        {!! $user->firstname !!} role granted by {!! $user->pivot->first_name !!}
    @endforeach
```

something like that..

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you need to use the Pivot class to give the pivot table its own model, Pivot extends Model and can have its own relationships.

[Laravel Docs: Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships)